# IOS set transparent border of path of cgcontext

Tags: ios, core-graphics, cgcontext, alpha-transparency

I have added a bezier path to my context as follows

```
for (Face* face in facesArray) {

    UIBezierPath* customPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [customPath moveToPoint:face.rightEyePosition];
    [customPath addQuadCurveToPoint:face.leftEyePosition controlPoint:face.foreheadPosition];
    [customPath addQuadCurveToPoint:face.mouthPosition controlPoint:face.lowerLeftContrlPoint];
    [customPath moveToPoint:face.rightEyePosition];
    [customPath addQuadCurveToPoint:face.mouthPosition controlPoint:face.lowerRightContrlPoint];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(originalImage.size, NO, 0.0);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextBeginPath (context);
    CGContextAddPath(context,customPath.CGPath);

    CGContextClosePath (context);
    CGContextClip (context);
    [imageView.image drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height)];

    UIImage* resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Above code crops the image according to bezier shape. I want borders of cropped image transparent. How should I set transparency to corners ob bezier path

Comment: you mean only border or total image's transparency ?  what color it has currently ?

Comment: I just need to set transparency around the border of bezier curve. Actually I crop the image from here and add that image to some other image. so I want to make its border transparent so that its border may not be prominent when I add this cropped Image to other

Comment: still not getting you ? what color it has currently ? is it UIImage or UIImageView u r talking about ? if its just UIImageView then you can use [yourImageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor ClearColor].CGColor];

Comment: I have cropped image through above code which is in irregular shape.
I have to add this cropped image over another image. But I want to make its corners(boundary of irregular shape) blended (transparent) so that cropped image may not look like that it has been placed over another image

Comment: any solution to that question yet?